# Difference in json.Unmarshal when using bytes.Buffer vs using *bytes.NewBuffer

Tags: go

I was looking at the bytes package. If I define a buffer using bytes.Buffer then the code below works and i get an output. However if I try create a buffer with a certain capacity and then try the same code it fails with the error error: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value. Not sure how to fix it.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var jsonBlob = []byte(`[
        {"Name": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
            {"Name": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
            ]`)

    //var b bytes.Buffer
    b := *bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 20))
    b.Write(jsonBlob)

    fmt.Println(b.String())

    var dat interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(b.Bytes(), &dat)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }   
    fmt.Printf("%+v", dat)
}
```

Output for Run with bytes.Buffer

```
[
        {"Name": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
        {"Name": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
    ]
[map[Name:Platypus Order:Monotremata] map[Name:Quoll Order:Dasyuromorphia]]
Program exited.
```

Output for Run with bytes.NewBuffer

```
[
        {"Name": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
        {"Name": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
    ]
error: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value
<nil>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [NewBuffer](https://godoc.org/bytes#NewBuffer) function uses the argument as the initial contents of the buffer. The call `make([]byte, 20)` returns a byte slice containing 20 zero bytes. The contents of the buffer after `b.Write(jsonBlob)` is 20 zero bytes followed by the JSON text.

Add `fmt.Printf("%q\n", b.String())` to the program to view the contents of the buffer.

<kbd>[playground example with printf added](https://play.golang.org/p/4xnF5Uo4Uc)</kbd>

The JSON parser complains about the first zero byte.

If your goal is to set the size of the internal buffer, use this code:

```
b := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, 20))
```

The call `make([]byte, 0, 20)` returns a zero length slice with capacity 20.

<kbd>[playground example with zero length slice](https://play.golang.org/p/f7jz8HDwOc)</kbd>

A variable of type `byte.Buffer` starts as the empty buffer.

If your goal is to limit the amount of data read, then use [io.LimitedReader](https://godoc.org/io#LimitedReader). For example:

```
f, err := os.Open("filename")
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
defer f.Close()
err := json.NewDecoder(&io.LimitedReader{N: 20, R: f}).Decode(&dat)
if err != nil {
    // handle error. Will get parse error if file is truncated. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to restrict the buffer to not grow ? Since inspite of setting the capacity to 20, when the size increases the buffer size grows till it hits overflow. Would I have to write my own Write method to do this ? Or is there a way to do this without having to write my own custom wrapper such as that in the eLitmus blog. (ref https://www.elitmus.com/blog/technology/custom-capacity-buffers-in-go/ )

Comment: It is not possible to restrict the size of bytes.Buffer.  Can you describe at higher level what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im trying to read contents of a file into a buffer and then parse the contents. However, if memory is full due to file size being too large, then my application will crash. Hence I wanted to preemptively restrict the buffer size and set a cap on it. This way when it reaches that cap, I can error out.

Comment: Use [io.LimitedReader](https://godoc.org/io#LimitedReader) as described in updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

read [this](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer):

> func NewBuffer
>
> func NewBuffer(buf []byte) *Buffer NewBuffer creates and initializes a
>   new Buffer using buf as its initial contents. It is intended to
>   prepare a Buffer to read existing data. It can also be used to size
>   the internal buffer for writing. To do that, buf should have the
>   desired capacity but a length of zero.
>
> In most cases, new(Buffer) (or just declaring a Buffer variable) is
>   sufficient to initialize a Buffer.

After `b.Write(jsonBlob)`, because your buffer din't have a length of zero(`make([]byte, 20)` creates a 20-length slice), so that `b.Bytes()` is 20 bytes you allocated plus the json content. Then when you do `Unmarshal`, the json parser will see 20 zeros in the beginning, of course it complains.

Comment: "So b.Bytes() is only 20 bytes" --- unless it's  not.https://play.golang.org/p/plSPmgWDVE

Comment: @zerkms my mistake. Edited.